# Trying to call Response->getInfo() fails even though it exist in the API

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to use Guzzle (~5.0) to get the equivalent of php `curl_getinfo`. The api says [it exists here](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Response.html#_getInfo), but when making the call I get an error that says:

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Message\Response::getInfo() in ...

I can `getBody()`, `getStatusCode()` and many other functions in `Response` without fail, but `getInfo()` does not work. Has it been deprecated? Is it a bug? Am I making the wrong call?

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;

class GuzzleCommand extends Command {

    public function fire()
    {

        $client = new Client();

        //equivalent of echo:
        $this->info($client->get('http://google.com')->getInfo());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a deprecated API, [as noted in this issue](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/828) with the `getInfo()` method, [this issue involving the API version](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/750) and [these upgrade documents as of v4.x](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/f4088880c57718a1c805dfa184ea8a97a6afed15/UPGRADING.md#responses):

> `GuzzleHttp\Message\Response::getInfo()` and `GuzzleHttp\Message\Response::setInfo()` have been removed. Use the event system to retrieve this type of information.

The [docs on the event system is here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/events.html).

Comment: Is there a link to the latest api version? I don't see anything in the current api docs to switch versions.

Comment: @Envious Unfortunately, no. [See this GitHub issue for the discussion around the outdated API docs](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/750)